# How can a projective matrix be a vector with length 8?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, transformation

A normal projection matrix has size 3*3 and has 9 values.
But [tensorflow transform](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/transform) needs a vector with dimension 8
So I don't know how to convert my matrix into this vector.

Example - I Have the matrix that does a rotation and a translation:

```
    top_row = [np.cos(rot_value), - np.sin(rot_value), trans_x]
    middle_row = [np.sin(rot_value), np.cos(rot_value), trans_y]
    last_row = [0, 0, 1]
    trans_matrix = np.stack((top_row, middle_row, last_row))
```

How can I convert this matrix in this vector with 8 dimensions so I can use tensorflow transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since projection matrix has a global scale ambiguity, you can multiply by a constant factor. Projective transformation has eight degrees of freedom, not nine, and the usual convention to remove this redundancy is to take the bottom right corner as 1.

For your case, you should be able to use `top_row + middle_row + [0, 0]`

More generally:

```
(trans_matrix/trans_matrix[2,2]).flat[:8]
```